# Gmsh installation problems: cannot launch GUI (FLTK libraries not found) and binary installation messes up geometry

Tags: user-interface, installation, ubuntu-16.04, mesh, fltk

For some reason, the Ubuntu Software lists very old version of gmsh (2.10.0) which does not have Boolean features. I need to use boolean operations so I wanted to upgrade to latest 3.0.6 version. apt-get upgrade didn't work.

1. I tried to use the binary installation from gmsh.info. Typing in, ./gmsh from bin directory open gmsh GUI however, it messes up geometry completely (for any given .geo file). The same geometries looked perfect in the previous 2.10.0 version. So I decided to do a clean install from source code.
2. I managed to install it and when I tried
   gmsh --version
   it gave me this:

   3.0.6

so I know that it has installed correctly.

However if I type in gmsh in the terminal, it doesn't open the GUI. Instead it gives me an output of:

```
gmsh -help
```

I figured out from cmake log that gmsh can't locate the FLTK libraries. Following is the latest log from cmake:

```
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of void*
-- Check size of void* - done
-- Found 64Bit
-- Performing Test STDCXX11
-- Performing Test STDCXX11 - Success
-- Found C++11
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- A library with BLAS API not found. Please specify library location.
-- Warning: Could not find Blas or Lapack: most meshing algorithms will not be functional
-- Found Mesh
-- Found Solver
-- Found Post
-- Found Plugins
-- Found Parser
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so  
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Could NOT find FLTK (missing:  FLTK_LIBRARIES) 
-- Found NativeFileChooser
-- Found ONELAB
-- Found ONELABMetamodel
-- System ANN not found: using contrib/ANN instead
-- Found Ann
-- Found Bfgs
-- Found DIntegration
-- Found OptHom
-- Found Kbipack
-- Found GMP
-- Found MathEx
-- Found Metis
-- Note: By including Metis you have to comply with Metis' special licensing requirements stated in contrib/Metis/README.txt.
-- Found Chaco
-- Found TetGen/BR
-- Found Voro3D
-- Found Blossom
-- Found Netgen
-- Found Bamg
-- System MMG3D not found: using contrib/mmg3d instead
-- Found Mmg3d
-- Found Tetgen1.5
--  Note: By including Tetgen you have to comply with Tetgen's special  licensing requirements stated in contrib/Tetgen1.5/LICENSE.
-- Could NOT find HDF5 (missing:  HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
-- HDF5 not found
-- System GMM not found: using contrib/gmm instead
-- Found Gmm
-- Found OpenCASCADE version 6.8.0 in /usr/include/oce
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1139 (message):
  Gmsh requires OpenCASCADE >= 6.9.1


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1140 (message):
  Use CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or the CASROOT environment variable to explicitely
  specify the installation path of OpenCASCADE


-- Looking for vsnprintf
-- Looking for vsnprintf - found
-- Looking for sys/socket.h
-- Looking for sys/socket.h - found
-- Check size of socklen_t
-- Check size of socklen_t - done
-- Check size of intptr_t
-- Check size of intptr_t - done
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - found
-- Found Dlopen
-- Looking for linux/joystick.h
-- Looking for linux/joystick.h - found
-- Found LinuxJoystick
-- Performing Test WALL
-- Performing Test WALL - Success
-- Performing Test WCAST
-- Performing Test WCAST - Failed
-- Performing Test WDEPREC
-- Performing Test WDEPREC - Success
-- Performing Test WIND
-- Performing Test WIND - Failed
-- Performing Test NOWARN
-- Performing Test NOWARN - Success
-- Performing Test NOOPT
-- Performing Test NOOPT - Success
-- 
-- Gmsh 3.0.6 has been configured for Linux64
-- 
--   * Build options: 64Bit Ann Bamg Bfgs Blossom C++11 Chaco DIntegration  Dlopen GMP Gmm Kbipack LinuxJoystick MathEx Mesh Metis Mmg3d  NativeFileChooser Netgen ONELAB ONELABMetamodel OptHom Parser Plugins  Post Solver TetGen/BR Tetgen1.5 Voro3D
--  * Build type: RelWithDebInfo
--  * C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
--  * C++ compiler: /usr/bin/c++
--  * Install prefix: /usr/local
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /opt/gmsh3.0.6
```

So from this log I know that it has trouble locating FLTK libraries (although I did install it before building gmsh) among other important warnings regarding meshing algorithm and so on..

The system has Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and gmsh is being installed in /opt/gmsh

Anyone knows what the issue could be? How do I launch gmsh GUI without any geometry mess up?

Comment: The "build-depends list" https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/gmsh ... says `libfltk1.3-dev`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However what do you suggest I do? Also, my m istake I didn't explicitely say this but I did install FLTK before going ahead, it seems it has trouble locating it anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libfltk1.3-dev
```